# Counting heads - Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, recurrence

Problem:

> Given integers n and k, along with `p1,p2,..., pn; where pi ε [0, 1]`, you want to determine the probability of obtaining exactly `k` heads when `n` biased coins are tossed independently at random, where p<sub>i</sub> is the probability that the i<sup>th</sup> coin comes up heads. Give an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm for this task. Assume you can multiply and add two numbers in [0, 1] in O(1) time.

Can somebody help me with developing the recurrence relation so that I may code it. (The question comes from back exercise of chapter Dynamic Programming in book "Algorithms By Dasgupta")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the situation when (n-1) coins are tossed together and nth coin is tossed apart and take into account mutual independence.

Combine probabilities of simpler cases to get P(1..n, k) (where P(1..n, k) is the probability of obtaining exactly k heads when n coins)

Then apply this rule and fill all the cells in NxK table

**Edit:**

There are two possible ways to get exactly k heads with n coins -

a) if (n-1) coins have k heads, and Nth coin is tail, and

b) if (n-1) coins have k-1 heads, and Nth coin is head

so

P(n, k) = P(n-1, k) * (1 - p[n]) + P(n-1, k-1) * p[n]

Comment: So can we use this recurrence relation:
P(N,K) = max { P(N-1,K), P(N-1,K-1)} + p<sub>i</sub>
And start with P(n,k)

Comment: sorry i dont know how to write subscript here. p<sub>i</sub> is p with  a subscript i

Comment: No, we don't need to choose maximum. You have to calc probability, not optimum of some kind.

Comment: So what will be the recurrence relation then?

Comment: I was hoping for your solution with some clues... OK, relation formula added